# SweetAlert lift the content and not make it stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

I have some problem in here, and I first time using alert in the sweet alert, I have a question about this topic why when I call my alert the content is up to lift and not stack with the alert? For the example like this :

[image]

I am confused about this, well I already follow the documentation to use this alert, and I didn't change anything for this style, I just call the javascript, and for the result like the image above.

js

```
let Swal = require('sweetalert2');
$(document).ready(function () {
   "use strict"
   $("#my-button").on('click', function () {
      Swal.fire(
           'The Internet?',
           'That thing is still around?',
           'question'
      )
   });
});
```

html

```
 <button type="submit" id="my-button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Sign In</button>
```

```js
Swal.fire(
  'The Internet?',
  'That thing is still around?',
  'question'
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.17.1/dist/sweetalert2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.17.1/dist/sweetalert2.css">
```

Does anyone have same the problem with me, when using sweet alert in the first time?

Comment: Can you describe what you're *expecting* to happen?  It's unclear what you mean by "*stack with the alert*" and "*the content is up to lift*"

Comment: sorry to make you confuse sir, so I expecting the alert is stacking on my input form or can call my form is still the same position on center, when I call that alert my input form is not center, I think when the alert show, the alert give some margin-top to make my content up to lift

Answer (score 0):

You can add some style based on sweetAlert2's classes.
Checkout this documentation: [Theming](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#theming)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will check the documentation again and make sure I don't make a fault, the link for documentation I use from this : https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage

Comment: yes I know u can take a look about theirs configurations https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration